# What do I lose if I am attacked?

Tags: castle-clash

In Castle Clash, if another player attacks my castle and destroys everything, what do I lose? Do I lose my heroes, my buildings, my money, or some combination of those?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are attacked you only lose Gold, Mana, and HB(Honor Badges). If your Heros die during the attack they will take a couple if minutes to recover. Your buildings, if you watch the attack, will be destroyed, but when you log on they are rebuilt, like the attack never happened. **EDIT:** you lose ~5 HB if you lose.